# Array becoming multi-dimensional in AJAX request

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, wordpress

So I am creating a function in WordPress which counts and sets a user session and storing its values in the user's local storage. I was able to make it work perfectly by using cookies and when the site is hosted locally, for some reason, it is not working when I uploaded it on the staging site. So I am trying implement this function using another approach and decided to use local storage instead.

There's a problem with the Array values that the function is generating and I have spent almost the entire day trying to debug the problem. It is generating multi-dimensional instead of a single one.

Here's my function  code:

```
function monitor_post_views() {
  $page_id = 'page' . $_POST['page_id'];
  $timestamp = time();  
  // 30 minutes timeout
  $timeout = 1800;
  // Serves as my guide for debugging, will not include in the final code
  $message = '';


  if ( ! empty($_POST['page_id_array']) ) {
     //Checks if values from local storage exist

     //Gets the stored Array coming from AJAX call
     $page_id_array[] = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['page_id_array']), true);

     if ( in_array_r($page_id_array, $page_id) ) {
        //Check if current page is found in array

        $message = 'FOUND IN ARRAY CHECKING !!!!';

        $temp= [];

        $page_id_array_temp = array('id' => $page_id, 'expiration' => $timestamp, 'message' => $message);

        $temp = $page_id_array_temp;

        //Pushes the generated array inside the $page_id_array
        array_push($page_id_array, $temp);

        print_r(json_encode($page_id_array));

        foreach ( $page_id_array as $page ) {
            //If page is in array, check if the session is expired, if not, do nothing, if expired, update and then run the view function
        }
    } else {
      // ID Not found in Array, Insert a new entry

      $message = 'ID NOT FOUND IN ARRAY, CREATING ENTRY !!!';

      $temp = [];

      $page_id_array_temp = array('id' => $page_id, 'expiration' => $timestamp, 'message' => $message);

      $temp = $page_id_array_temp;

      //Pushes the generated array inside the $page_id_array
      array_push($page_id_array, $temp);

      print_r(json_encode($page_id_array));

      //Set post view function here base on $_POST['page_id']

    }

  } else {
    //Not found in local storage, need to create one

    $message = 'CREATING A NEW ENTRY !!!!';

    $temp = [];

    $page_id_array = array('id' => $page_id, 'expiration' => $timestamp, 'message' => $message);

    $temp = $page_id_array;

    print_r(json_encode($temp));

    //Set post view function here base on $_POST['page_id']

  }

  wp_die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_monitor_post_views', 'monitor_post_views');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_monitor_post_views', 'monitor_post_views');
```

Here's a screenshot of what this function generates

[Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9WQ7.png)

Here's a sample JSON

```
[[{"id":"page1202","expiration":1551125579,"message":"FOUND IN ARRAY CHECKING !!!!"},{"id":"page1206","expiration":1551125613,"message":"ID NOT FOUND IN ARRAY !!!! INSERTING ENTRY !!!"}],{"id":"page1296","expiration":1551125624,"message":"ID NOT FOUND IN ARRAY !!!! INSERTING ENTRY !!!"}]
```

I was trying to generate a one dimensional but ended up with this.
Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a sample of the JSON (from `$_POST['page_id_array']`)?

Comment: [[{"id":"page1202","expiration":1551125579,"message":"FOUND IN ARRAY CHECKING !!!!"},{"id":"page1206","expiration":1551125613,"message":"ID NOT FOUND IN ARRAY !!!! INSERTING ENTRY !!!"}],{"id":"page1296","expiration":1551125624,"message":"ID NOT FOUND IN ARRAY !!!! INSERTING ENTRY !!!"}]

Here you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating arrays too many times:

Change $page_id_array and $page_id_array_temp to

```
 $page_id_array=new \stdClass();//no need to declare as an array
```

replace

```
$page_id_array_temp = array('id' => $page_id, 'expiration' => $timestamp, 'message' => $message);
```

with

```
 $page_id_array->id=$page_id;
 $page_id_array->expiration=$timestamp;
 $page_id_array->message=$message;
```

also change

```
$temp = [];
```

you can use it directly 
//no need to declare $temp as an array

```
 $temp=$page_id_array;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. 
I  created a  temp object and retained the temp array. After defining the keys of the object. I parsed them and assigned it to $temp. I used array_push() to append it on the existing array.